# Trying to retrieve Facts from Drools Working Memory

Tags: java, drools, drools-fusion

I am trying to search and retrieve a fact from the Drools Working Memory using a `FactHandle` but unable to do so. I am using the `kieSession.getFactHandle(object)` method in order to retrieve the fact, but it returns NullPointerException every time. Please correct me if I am implementing the `FactHandle` the wrong way. Below is my implementation:

```java
Person person = new Person().setName("David").setAge(33);
FactHandle factHandle = kieSession.getFactHandle(person);
kieSession.update(factHandle, person); // NullPointerException
```

Comment: There are a lot of tests in the Drools codebase using the getFactHandle method, maybe you should start from that? This question is a bit too generic

Comment: @LucaMolteni Am I going in the wrong direction for searching a fact on the working memory?

Comment: So is this basically that you fired your rules and are now trying to get data out?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I am trying to search the fact. consider a select query in case of SQL.

Comment: That's even less clear than your question ... @sam

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have inserted the Person object to kieSession. Now I want to retrieve it.

Comment: So you insert the Person into working memory, fire the rules, and now retrieve the Person? Do you not have the reference from when you inserted it?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I donot have any reference to the person object but I do know the values of the field contained in the object.